# Remove current line from file

Tags: python, python-3.x

Consider a file with the following lines:

```
remove   
keep
remove
```

Is it possible to remove the current line while iterating the file lines?

```
for word in file:
    if word != "keep":
        remove_line_from_file
```

In the end the file should just the line with word keep.
I know I could create a file with the remaining words but I was hoping to keep the same file.

Comment: Wouldn't keeping the file be the same as overwriting the file with the lines removed?

Comment: You can't modify the file while you're reading it. Save what you want to keep in a list, then rewrite the file at the end.

Comment: @Barmar Python has a library function for inplace editing: [**`fileinput.input`**](https://docs.python.org/3/library/fileinput.html#fileinput.input)

Comment: with open('text.txt', 'r+') as f:
        line = 'x'
        read_ptr = 0
        previos_write_ptr = 0
        write_ptr = 0
        while line:
            line = f.readline()
            print(line)
            read_ptr = f.tell()
            if line.strip() == 'keep':
                f.seek(write_ptr)
                f.write(line)
                write_ptr = f.tell()
                f.seek(read_ptr)
    
        f.seek(write_ptr)
        f.truncate()

Answer (score 2):

Python has a nice library named [**`fileinput`**](https://docs.python.org/3/library/fileinput.html#fileinput.input) which allows you to modify files inplace. You can print what you want to keep back into the file:

```
with fileinput.input(filename, inplace=True) as lines:
    for line in lines:
        if line == 'keep':
            print(line,)
```

Answer (score 0):

No, but you can extract all the contents of the file beforehand, 
modify the text, and then rewrite them back into the file:

```
with open('file.txt','r') as f:
    lines = f.readlines()

with open('file.txt','w') as f:
    f.write(''.join([ln for ln in lines if 'keep' in ln])) # Writes all the lines back to file.txt that has the word `keep` in them
```

Comment: What if the file is 100 GB?

Comment: Is it a `txt` file?

Comment: Does it make a difference?

Comment: Well, I think python can handle a 100gb txt file.

Comment: How much memory does your machine have? `readlines` will attempt to read the whole file into memory, and you'll get a `MemoryError`

Comment: I guess i was wrong.